# How to do LEFT JOIN in LINQ to Entities?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have spent the last 2 days trying to find out how to do a real LEFT JOIN in LINQ and I haven't been successful.
I have a user table that has a "Primary2Address" column in it that could and is often NULL.
so I have to do a LEFT JOIN here. In addition, in the Address table, I have more relationship that could be NULL, so I have to do multiple LEFT JOINS.
Every LINQ attempt i do outputs some SERIOUSLY CRAZY sql statements with UNIONS, nested SELECT statements and more wacky things.
All i need is:

```
SELECT u.UserName FROM Users u 
LEFT JOIN Addresses a ON a.AddressiD = u.Primary2Address
LEFT JOIN States s ON s.StateID = a.Address2State
LEFT JOIN Countries c ON c.CountryID = a.CountryID
```

**Please help!** So far my work-around was to create a stored procedure that uses my sql statement above, but I would really like to try to do this with LINQ (L2E).
Thanks guys!

Comment: How does your query differ from just `SELECT u.UserName FROM Users u`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`DefaultIfEmpty` is used for left joins for EntityFramework 4+

```
var query = from u in context.Users
            from a in context.Addresses
                             .Where(x => u.Primary2Address == x.AddressiD)
                             .DefaultIfEmpty()
            from s in context.States
                             .Where(x => a.Address2State == x.StateID)
                             .DefaultIfEmpty()
            from c in context.Countries
                             .Where(x => a.CountryID == x.CountryID)
                             .DefaultIfEmpty()
            select u.UserName;
```

Comment: You are my hero!  Wow, after so many hours.... Your query is as straight forward as they come and i get it now.
Thanks a million Aducci !

Comment: As per @svick's comment on the question, how does this differ from `from u in context.Users select u.UserName` ?

Comment: @AakashM - If any user has multiple addresses you would get a different result. More importantly, I think the question has been simplified.

Comment: What does `DefaultIfEmpty` return? MSDN says *it returns default valued singleton collection if the sequence is empty.*

Comment: @IanBoyd - if the type is a class it will return null, if the type is an integer it will return 0, etc...